# Hide specific tables inside a div

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML inside my sharepoint page:-

```
<div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_WebTreeView">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
</div>
```

Now I want to hide all the tables inside the div except for the third table. Can anyone advise? I used to hide the first table using the following :-

```
#ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_WebTreeView > table:first-child { display: none !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `:not`, and `:nth-child(n)` selector:

```
#ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_WebTreeView > table:not(:nth-child(3)) {
    display: none;
}
```

- `:not(selector)` selects every element, except the one matching the selector inside the parentesis.
- `nth-child` select the elements that are the nth child of its parent.

**Also**

Avoid using `!important`, unless you really need it. It will mess up your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:not` selector

```
#ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_WebTreeView > table:not(:nth-child(3)) { 
    display: none !important;
 }
```

`:not` selects other than the `child-element` mentioned in it.

`!important` overrides any previous property used for the table.

Answer (score 0):

In the event that you need to support IE8 or below, the `:not` / `:nth-child` selectors will be unsupported (although `:first-child` **is** supported in IE8). If that is the case, I would suggest adding some inline styling to the third table.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_WebTreeView">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0; display:block;">

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_WebTreeView > table { display:none; }
```

I don't think you should have any trouble with the CSS overriding your inline styling, but if this did happen you could consider using `!important`. Although using `!important` is often not great practise and requires careful consideration, I tend to use it if supporting IE8 makes it a necessity.

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0; display:block !important;">
```